# Does style="color: #FFF;" render as #F0F0F0 or #FFFFFF?

Tags: html, css, colors, hex

When defining colors using "shorthand hexidecimal" (`style="color: #FFF;"`), is there a defined method for expanding the shorthand? (`style="color: #F0F0F0;"` or `style="color: #FFFFFF;"`)

Do all browsers use the same expansion method? Is this behavior by specification (if so, where is it defined)? Does the expansion method perhaps vary between CSS 1/2/3?

I've observed that "most browsers" expand to `#FFFFFF`.

Are there any other places (outside of HTML/CSS) where this shorthand notation is allowed, but the expansion method is different?

I've always avoided using shorthand hex, because I've never known the answers to these questions...

Comment: I always kinda assumed it expanded to `#ffffff` and never really questioned it... good question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

CSS 2.1 (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-color):

> The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies on the color depth of the display.

Wordings of [CSS 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#color-units), [CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color) are the same. The [CSS 4 draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation) say similar things.

The [Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531197.aspx#rgb) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb) docs state the same method.

As a practical example, please check out this snippet, which features 3 `<div>`s of styles

```css
div { width: 100px; height: 100px;  }
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#f0f0f0;">#f0f0f0</div>
<div style="background-color:#fff;">#fff</div>
<div style="background-color:#ffffff;">#ffffff</div>
```

On Mac OS X 10.6, all Firefox 3.6, Opera 10.10, Safari 4 rendered `#fff` as `#ffffff`.

[image: Behavior in different browsers]

I don't see a reason why a browser or the standard wants to deviate from this expansion in the future, since the color `#ffffff` is far more common than `#f0f0f0`.

Answer (score 18):

The [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#color-units) section 4.3.6 Colors:

> The RGB color model is used in
>   numerical color specifications. These
>   examples all specify the same color:
>
> ```
> em { color: #f00 }              /* #rgb */
> em { color: #ff0000 }           /* #rrggbb */
> em { color: rgb(255,0,0) }      
> em { color: rgb(100%, 0%, 0%) }
> ```
>
> The format of an RGB value in
>   hexadecimal notation is a '#'
>   immediately followed by either three
>   or six hexadecimal characters. The
>   three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is
>   converted into six-digit form
>   (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not
>   by adding zeros. For example, #fb0
>   expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that
>   white (#ffffff) can be specified with
>   the short notation (#fff) and removes
>   any dependencies on the color depth of
>   the display.

Since all modern browsers support CSS you can assume it will work this way in your web sites and web applications.

Answer (score 6):

Testing on IE8, Firefox 3.6, and Google Chrome 5.0 beta, all three browsers repeat the hex digit:

- 000 produces 000000
- FFF produces FFFFFF
- 876 produces 887766

...and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

I feel I should encourage people to not do this, as it is equivalent to telling someone you want 15 of something and then expecting them to show up with 255. What a gross and strange way to shorthand 0xFFFFFF. This is the "r u there" of web design to me.

Comment: It seems more succinct to me. If they're equivalent, shouldn't we prefer brevity? Is there a practical reason to prefer six digits, or is it just up to personal taste?

Answer (score 1):

I've not known a browser to not expand #FFF to #FFFFFF. I'd be interested in knowing which you think doesn't - or do you mean some continue to show #FFF?

However, as I understood it, the #FFF is valid shorthand, and #F0 would also (validly) expand to #F0F0F0.

This might be of interest http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/hex/

Comment: Instinctively, I have some doubt about #F0 expanding to #F0F0F0 but I could be wrong