# Can't convert hex color to rgb because of int representation

Tags: objective-c, colors, hex, converters, uicolor

I'm downloading hex color from web and when I try to convert it to RGB it's not working.

I'm using this function:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

I think the problem is that when I get value from internet (for example 000) when I convert it to int so I can pass it as argument to function above, int is represented just as 0 so function doesn't recognize the color. Same thing for example with 090 when in int its 90.

Comment: This worked for me. http://code.wrightscs.com/?p=65 You just give the function the hex code

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of the hex colour as a string and process each component separately.

The colour #3B9 has digits "3" "B" and "9"

However, looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899197/does-style-color-fff-render-as-f0f0f0-or-ffffff) you will see that for 3 digit representation, characters are doubled.

So in this case the colour is actually #33BB99:
red = 3*16+3 = 51
green = 11*16+11 = 187
blue = 8*16+8 = 136
alpha = 255

So the colour '#3B9' would become:
[51/255.0, 187/255.0, 136/255.0, 1.0]

So you should first determine if the string is representing colours in a compressed way and duplicate digits if necessary. Then convert the pairs of digits to their decimal value and then convert to UIColor.

Hope that helps, and I hope my calculations are correct. I am not good with objective-C so I wont provide code, but it should be easy enough to write your own function, although I would bet that function already exists somewhere.