# A difference in CSS

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

so today i have a "semantic question?":

what's the difference between

```
#fff          
              and
#ffffff
```

in CSS?

I mean, is there some problem with cross-browser?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899197/does-style-color-fff-render-as-f0f0f0-or-ffffff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#fff` is just short-hand for `#ffffff`. They mean the exact same thing to the browser.

Any `#XXYYZZ` hex code can be represented this way in CSS, i.e `#ffccdd` --> `#fcd` or `#cc0099` -> `#c09`. Given that this behavior has been around for decades, there should be no cross-browser difficulties.

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#color-units

> The format of an RGB value in hexadecimal notation is a '#' immediately followed by either three or six hexadecimal characters. The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This makes sure that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies on the color depth of the display.

Answer (score 0):

The triplet is still technically hexadecimal but it is a shortcut. All it does is repeat each of the values and use that for the RGB. `#333` becomes `#333333`, `#abc` becomes `#aabbcc` etc.
I think the reasons for using this are two-fold: very minor space savings and values of R, G and B stepped by 16 evenly which helps proper colour reproduction on low-colour devices (the hex triplet would give a range of 4096 unique colour values). Nowadays that is becoming less useful since so many devices can display large numbers of colours natively.